# The need of user with out log in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

what is the need of user with out log in in SQL Server?

There is a contained database. I have created a user who can log into the contained database.

How to port the database to another server without additional user configuration?

Is the "user with out log"  is going to help in this context?

Want to know more about users with out log in

Experts..please share your views

Comment: Why have you tagged this 2008/2005/2008-R2 and 2012? Contained databases are 2012+.

Comment: I think user with out log in is present in all other SQL versions from SQL 2000 to upwards.My main question is "what is the need of user with out log in in sql server?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users that don't have a login are users that exist only at the database level and therefore you cannot log in to the server with them.

They can however be assigned permissions and can be used to sign modules within those databases.

The most common uses I see for them during my day to day work are either loginless users that are created from a certificate which is then used to sign stored procedures, this means that the user actually logging in to SQL server requires very few permissions in the database and all the work is done in the context of the loginless user, helping to increase security.

I also see loginless users that are not created from certificates, but are made owners of schemas or procedures which then execute as owner, similar to the above, this means that the user lgging in only needs execute rights on the procedure, no table access at all.